# Iterating through PHP array with duplicate records and deleting one record where a value = 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, laravel

I have a MySQL query using Laravel that I convert to a PHP Array.

The rows have values similar to this:

```
name | override | percentage
Eclipse | 1 | 50%
Eclipse | 0 | 75%
```

MySQL query

`select * from table`

Both rows (it's many more than just 2 in reality) have the same name, but one has override set to 0 and one has it set to 1.

How can I get rid of all records in my query result (PHP array) that are duplicates (determined by the name) AND have override set to 0?   I want only the records that have been overridden with a new record which I have done, but I need a way to remove the records with override = 0, given that the records are the same but have a different percentage value.

How can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do it directly in your MySQL query ? This way you just get the good result with PHP

Comment: How can I do it in MySQL?

Comment: I'd assumed it would require some array manipulation to do this given the complexity.

Comment: Update your question with your current MySQL query

Comment: @JustinIurman ok lol.  Done.  In reality it's MUCH much larger.  The query has about 10 joins and is selecting hundreds of records.  I've just used the above as an example.  It's the same concept but I've just provided the columns rows above to simplify the explanation.

Comment: Are you kidding me ? I think `select * from table` is a little too much simplified...

Comment: Not really...  That's essentially what it is.  I'm selecting values from multiple tables with some joins.

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c56f4a/2 ; is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Doing this in SQL will be WAYYYYYYYYY faster and use far less memory. I would only try this PHP approach if you cannot modify the SQL for some reason.

Maybe try out... hit the db twice, first time only get non-overrides, then get the overrides in second pass -- coerce your arrays to be indexed by name and array_merge them. (Uses a fair chunk of memory given the number of arrays and copies - but it's easy to understand and keeps it simple.

```
$initial = get_non_overridden();
$override = get_overridden();
$init_indexed = index_by_name($initial);
$over_indexed = index_by_name($override);

$desired_result = array_merge($init_indexed, $over_indexed);
```

Assuming your database gives you a standard rowset (array of rows, where each row is a hash of fields->values). We want something that looks like this instead:

```
[
  'Eclipse' => [
    'name' => 'Eclipse',
    'override' => '0',
    'percentage' => '75%'
  ],
  'Something' => [
    'name' => 'Something',
    'override' => '0',
    'percentage' => '20%'
  ],
]
```

So index_by_name would be:

```
function index_by_name($rowset) {
  $result = array();
  foreach ($rowset as $row) {
    $result[ $row['name'] ] = $row;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

There are ways to tweak your efficiency either in memory or run time, but that's the gist of what I was thinking.

array_merge then overwrites the initial ones with the overridden ones.

NOTE: this all assumes that there is only one row where Eclipse override is 1. If you have twenty Eclipse|0 and one Eclipse|1, this will work, if you have two Eclipse|1 you'd only see one of them... and there's no way to say which one.

Comment: What should the index_by_name function do?

Comment: Selected this as the answer because it solved my problem whereas the others did not.

Answer (score 1):

Try following query,

```
SELECT * from testtable GROUP BY `name` HAVING count(`name`) = 1 OR `override` = 1;
```

check this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8867/1)

Comment: This is only showing the records with override = 1.

Comment: Please check sqlfiddle, it also displays records with override = 0, the secound records Notepad one has overrride = 0

Comment: Ok I see i've added this to my query, and it's now not returning the records that have duplicate names whatsoever.

Comment: Do you mean that, if there are 3 records of Eclipse, one with override=1 and two with override=0 then returning 2 records one with the override=1 and one with override = 0 instead of three records?

Comment: No what I mean is it's returning NO records with override = 1.

Comment: If you just whacked the group by and having on the end of your (much more complex) sql... it might work differently... try wrapping... like: SELECT * FROM (your original sql) AS orig GROUP BY `name` HAVING count(`name`) = 1 OR `override` = 1;

Comment: In this case you should put your original query in here, because you can check the sqlfiddle it's working there means it should work for you also and if it is not working then this means there is something wrong in query you are testing

Comment: Can I message you the query somehow?  Would prefer not to post it publicly.

Comment: do you want records with duplicate names if those records both have `override = 1`?

Comment: @deacs that would never happen.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your needs correctly, you need to filter out records that have duplicate name and `override = 0`.

If you sort your result set by `name` (`SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY name`), you can use this function.

```
function removeDuplicatesFromArray($rows) {
    $result = array();
    $old_name = '';
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if($row['name'] != $old_name) {
            $result[] = $row;
            $old_name = $row['name'];
        }
        elseif($row['override'] == 1) {
            array_pop($result);
            $result[] = $row;             
        }       
    }
    return $result; 
}
```